# User defined devices don't show up on the device definitions list

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-virtual-device

I'm just getting started on an app idea I had to automate some things that my computer does through my phone. I had the sdk downloaded from before but I couldn't get it to let me define a user device. I thought it was a bug with the old install of the sdk so I deleted everything including the `.android` folder and reinstalled it again but to no avail. My custom devices still are not showing up on the list.

When I try to add a custom device definition, I go through all the steps, the device shows up under the Device Definitions tab, it is written (poorly formatted) in XML to `<username>/.android/devices.xml` but it doesn't show up in the list of devices when I try to create a new AVD and when I restart, the device is gone from the Device Definition list too.

I am using Windows 8 Pro x64 with Eclipse Juno, SDK Manager 21.0.1 (this was downloaded on 12/22/2012 around 2 AM). The only plugins I have in Eclipse are Subversive, ADT and the Eclipse Marketplace if that matters.

Also here are the contents of `<username>/.android/devices.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<d:devices xmlns:d="http://schemas.android.com/sdk/devices/1" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <d:device>
    <d:name>Droid DNA</d:name>
    <d:manufacturer>User</d:manufacturer>
    <d:meta/>
    <d:hardware>
      <d:screen>
        <d:screen-size>large</d:screen-size>
        <d:diagonal-length>5.00</d:diagonal-length>
        <d:pixel-density>xxhdpi</d:pixel-density>
        <d:screen-ratio>long</d:screen-ratio>
        <d:dimensions>
          <d:x-dimension>1080</d:x-dimension>
          <d:y-dimension>1920</d:y-dimension>
        </d:dimensions>
        <d:xdpi>440.58</d:xdpi>
        <d:ydpi>440.58</d:ydpi>
        <d:touch>
          <d:multitouch>jazz-hands</d:multitouch>
          <d:mechanism>finger</d:mechanism>
          <d:screen-type>capacitive</d:screen-type>
        </d:touch>
      </d:screen>
      <d:networking>
NFC
Wifi
Bluetooth</d:networking>
      <d:sensors>
ProximitySensor
Gyroscope
LightSensor
Barometer
Compass
Accelerometer
GPS</d:sensors>
      <d:mic>true</d:mic>
      <d:camera>
        <d:location>front</d:location>
        <d:autofocus>true</d:autofocus>
        <d:flash>true</d:flash>
      </d:camera>
      <d:camera>
        <d:location>back</d:location>
        <d:autofocus>true</d:autofocus>
        <d:flash>true</d:flash>
      </d:camera>
      <d:keyboard>nokeys</d:keyboard>
      <d:nav>nonav</d:nav>
      <d:ram unit="GiB">2</d:ram>
      <d:buttons>hard</d:buttons>
      <d:internal-storage unit="GiB">
4</d:internal-storage>
      <d:removable-storage unit="TiB"/>
      <d:cpu>Generic CPU</d:cpu>
      <d:gpu>Generic GPU</d:gpu>
      <d:abi>
armeabi
mips
armeabi-v7a
x86</d:abi>
      <d:dock/>
      <d:power-type>battery</d:power-type>
    </d:hardware>
    <d:software>
      <d:api-level>-</d:api-level>
      <d:live-wallpaper-support>true</d:live-wallpaper-support>
      <d:bluetooth-profiles/>
      <d:gl-version>2.0</d:gl-version>
      <d:gl-extensions/>
      <d:status-bar>false</d:status-bar>
    </d:software>
    <d:state default="true" name="Portrait">
      <d:description>The device in portrait orientation</d:description>
      <d:screen-orientation>port</d:screen-orientation>
      <d:keyboard-state>keyssoft</d:keyboard-state>
      <d:nav-state>navhidden</d:nav-state>
    </d:state>
    <d:state name="Landscape">
      <d:description>The device in landscape orientation</d:description>
      <d:screen-orientation>land</d:screen-orientation>
      <d:keyboard-state>keyssoft</d:keyboard-state>
      <d:nav-state>navhidden</d:nav-state>
    </d:state>
  </d:device>
</d:devices>
```

Please help me out, I found a solution while trying to google this problem where the AVD would write ',' instead of '.' to specify decimal places but that was more of a locale issue, though I checked that mine didn't do that anyway.

Answer (score 0):

We meet this problem as well.
After several experiments, We find it shows properly by replacing xxhdpi to xhdpi.
I consider this may be a bug in this version.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, this sounds like an issue that more than one have had a few problems with. Before Android SDK Tools 21.1 (actually I think this was addressed in an RC2 as well), there was an issue with parsing xxhdpi device definitions and the AVD device list. If you try and update the Android SDK Tools to version 21.1 I believe your issues will be resolved.